# C# - how to get a List<List<string>> from an ArrayList?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I'm stumped, and could be being very stupid - but I can't figure this one out.

I have some data which is being converted to an `ArrayList`. The data looks like this:

> [ ["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"] ]

So essentially, it's an array of string arrays. I'd love to get it into this format `List<List<string>>`, so I can access and manipulate the data easily - but I can't figure out how to do it!

As `ArrayList` is not strongly typed, I'm getting into a world of trouble trying to cast the first element of the `ArrayList` into anything useful.

As you can see from the snippet below, the `ArrayList` has two elements, each with 26 elements (which is representative of my data, there's two entries of 26 strings).

[image]

Can anyone show me how to turn an `ArrayList` representation of the data above, into a `List<List<string>>` please?

Thanks!!

Comment: So it's an `ArrayList` of arrays? or an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`? Or an `ArrayList` of something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with non-generic collections, you can use some LINQ if you perform a `Cast<>()` or filter using `OfType<>()`.  Assuming these are homogeneous collections, you can do this:

```
arrList.Cast<IEnumerable>()
       .Select(enumerable => enumerable.Cast<string>()
                                       .ToList())
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Jeff - thanks! This works a treat. And to boot, I understand it totally. I'll stick this one in my memory bank. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would do it

```
List<List<string>> listlistString = arrList.Cast<IEnumerable>()
    .Select(ienum => ienum.Cast<string>().ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - but an `ArrayList` does not have Select though...?

Comment: `.Cast<string>().Select(x => x.ToString())` is redundant - it's already `string`, so why do another `.ToString()`?

Comment: Hey JB - thanks, I think this would do the trick now.. I tried Jeff's answer before I saw your update, so I marked that one as the answer. Cheers for the quick response though :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair whoops, fixed. Can anyone tell it's been awhile since I've had to deal with ArrayLists? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
List<List<string>> result = myarraylist.Cast<string[]>()
                                       .Select(x => x.ToList())
                                       .ToList();
```

Comment: returns nothing unfortunately. Jeff's answer casting to IEnumerable gives the correct results. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Stretch: It works at my end. I added in my arraylist `myal.Add(new string[]{"a", "b", "c"})` and `myal.Add(new string[]{"1", "2", "3"})` and ran my code. Worked as a charm. What is happening at your place which does not work.

Comment: not sure.. I just tried yours again, and still returns nothing. I guess it must be with the way the data is setup originally? as in, you are setting up the `ArrayList` with a string array, whereas my `ArrayList` would just have a list of objects..?

Comment: @Stretch: Well in that case use `Cast<string[]>()` instead of `OfType<string[]>()`. Does it work now?

Comment: He actually had an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` so that wouldn't work neither.  In general, it's better to cast to a less-specific type so you won't run into problems such as this.

Comment: @JeffMercado: From what OP described I made out that its an arraylist of string[]. Now i have changed my answer for arraylist of object. How is it now?

Comment: Yeah, the wording was a bit confusing I admit. He said it was "essentially an array of string arrays" so it sounded like there were actually arrays. But the use of the word "essentially" meant it was _used_ like that, not necessarily that it was _actually_ that. I asked about that [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877425/c-sharp-how-to-get-a-listliststring-from-an-arraylist/10877533#comment14174998_10877425) and he confirmed it was an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`.